# Is there a more efficient way to slip columns than pivoting table or using XML and Nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there are other methods to split columns or much better methods than these two

I am going to put some code so we can talk the same language

```
--CREATING TABLE
CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
ID VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
) 
/*
  BOOKS 
  PRODUCTID, NAME, PAGES, WEIGHT, SIZE, TYPE
*/
INSERT INTO BOOKS (ID)
VALUES('B001,INTRODUCTION TO SQL,500,100G,MID,TECH')
      ,('B002,ADVANCED SQL SERVER PRACTICES,200,200G,BIG,TECH')
      ,('B003,SQL SERVER PERFORMANCE,1000,500G,BIG,TECH')
      ,('B004,SQL SERVER MANUAL,50,30G,SMALL,TECH')
          ,('B004,SQL SERVER MANUAL,50,30G,SMALL,TECH')
```

That will be my demo table, as you can see I have a table with comma separated values

For splitting this values I am going to use pivot combined with a CTE

```
/*PIVOTING TABLE, ASIGNING A RN TO COLUMNS AND GETTING BACK VALUES*/
WITH C AS(
SELECT ID
      ,value 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM BOOKS BO
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ID, ',') AS BK
)
SELECT ID
      ,[1] AS PRODUCTID
      ,[2] AS NAME
      ,[3] AS PAGES
      ,[4] AS WEIGHT
      ,[5] AS SIZE
      ,[6] AS TYPE
FROM C
PIVOT(
    MAX(VALUE)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])  
) as PVT
```

It works fine but in this case the order of strings that it returns is not guaranteed (Ex, 1,2,3,4). column1 = 1, column2 = 3 column3=2 column4 =4, and I am expecting to get 1,2,3,4
The other one is a well known here in stackoverflow by using XML and Nodes

The other one is a well known here in stackoverflow by using XML and Nodes

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS PRODUCTID
   ,S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)')  AS NAME
   , S.a.value('(/H/r)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS PAGES
   , S.a.value('(/H/r)[4]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS WEIGHT
   , S.a.value('(/H/r)[5]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SIZE
   , S.a.value('(/H/r)[6]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS TYPE
FROM
(
SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + REPLACE(ID, ',', '</r><r>')  
               + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
FROM BOOKS) d 
CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
```

Also it works as expected, but don't get me wrong, it is hard to explain and a little confusing if you are not above the beginner level.

What other better ways are there to split columns in sql server, do microsoft implement a new function for this or do you know another method for doing it. ?

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data at all? That data should clearly be 6 separate columns to start with, and so your table `BOOKS` should have 6 columns, not 1.

Comment: I had this scenario lots of times when dealing with customer data at job, believe me data is not always structured specially when working doing data analysis

Comment: See this article https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function.  It describes a splitter function that also returns column orders

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2017

Comment: You, should have a look at the improved version of that, @user1443098: [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)

Comment: @AlvaroParra That's a great find!  (Even Jeff Moden likes it!!)  And of course, it can solve the OPs problem

Comment: That was me, @user1443098, not Alvaro. ;) And yes, Eirikur spoke a lot to Jeff about the function before he published it (with his "blessing"). Those 2 functions are a great example of the community over at SSC, in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu Ooops, sorry for the wrong attribution.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my method would be to treat the value as what it is, a delimited item, and then pivot it using a cross tab. As ordinal position is important, and `STRING_SPLIT` does not guarentee this, then [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) is a far better option here:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS PRODUCTID,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS [NAME],
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS PAGES,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 4 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS WEIGHT,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 5 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS SIZE,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 6 THEN NULLIF(DS.Item,'') END) AS [TYPE]
FROM dbo.BOOKS B
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(B.ID,',') DS
GROUP BY B.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If 2016+, yet another option is JSON.

JSON seems to outperform XML, especially in Select Fragment and Select Value ( [ref](https://hackernoon.com/xml-vs-json-shootout-which-should-i-use-in-sql-server-7eefa4dc7553)  )

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=16a8f84d6dc67dcb5fd422f219190cf1)**

```
Select B.* 
 From BOOKS A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Pos1= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[0]')
                     ,Pos2= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[1]')
                     ,Pos3= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[2]')
                     ,Pos4= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[3]')
                     ,Pos5= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[4]')
                     ,Pos6= JSON_VALUE(J,'$[5]')
                From (values ('["'+replace(replace(ID,'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]'))A(J)
             ) B
```

Comment: Have you benched it agains https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2?

Comment: @user1443098 I don't think I'd have to.  As impressive as Larnu's function is, it is still a table-valued function and aggregation vs a native function.

Comment: Well IIRC (though memory is tricky!) I think Jeff's benchmarks showed that is not always the case.

Comment: Personally, on my Home Workstation (i7 8700 32GB RAM), with 630 rows I found `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` to take 10ms, where as the JSON solution on average 16ms. At 3130: 48~ vs 83~. Oddly, at 15000~ rows they were on par, and then at 80,000~ rows JSON was much slower (1000ms~ vs 2000ms~). At 400000~ rows, JSON was seconds slower. Native functions aren't always better. look at the awful `FORMAT` function, for example. :)

Comment: I did discuss the JSON solution with Jeff awhile ago (years), @user1443098 . I'll see if i can find the topic with my GoogleFu.

Comment: @Larnu The FORMAT function was a cheap shot :)

Comment: Sorry, @JohnCappelletti, I couldn't resist. That function needs to be fixed (removed from all versions); even more so than the much needed amendment to `STRING_SPLIT` so that it *does* return ordinal position.

Comment: @Larnu  The functionality of format is commendable, but should only be used sparingly on small data sets.  Made my brain bleed that string_split did not maintain the ordinal.     Your test results seem a little inconsistent.  Next time I am in the Data Lab, I will run some benchmarks as well.   We'll have some fun.

Comment: I'll script out a proper test process later, and see how it comes out later tonight @JohnCappelletti :)

Comment: Weird.  I used the Popular Baby Names CSV from the US GOV, de-csv'd it, then ran with the JSON solution and the improved function.  The improved function was faster but interestingly, the JSON solution above *returned more rows that in the source*.  Haven't figured that out yet...

Comment: @user1443098 just curious, how many rows and approximate times

Comment: Might be because I aggregate on the value of `ID` and you were duplicating the values of `ID` in your dataset? As a result, regardless of the number of rows; you'll get 5, unless you group on a different column.

Comment: There are 19418 rows, with about 7000 dups (hence the difference between my tests, since i used ```PIVOT(MAX(B.Item) FOR ItemNumber IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) p```.  The function (with pivot) took 777745 microsecs. The JSON took 1614896 microsecs.  This is entirely unscientific of course.  Just a seat-of-the-pants approach.

Comment: @user1443098  Sorry guys but I'm seeing the complete opposite,  Parsing 100K NewID()'s on the dash, the JSON is consistently twice as fast.  Running 10 passes each:  8K >>>  563 / 626 / 591   (min / max / avg ms) while JSON >>> 247 / 270 / 256 (min / max / avg ms)   Again, when I'm back in the Data Lab, I'll run some benchmarks.

Comment: I guess we should just say YMMV

Comment: @user1443098 Posted a quick script on dbFiddle.  Full disclosure, had to bring it down to 10,000 records and 5 passes because it kept on timing out.  BUT here is the odd part, 8K performs better here ...  350ms vs 572ms     I'm done beating this mule for now  :)

Comment: @user1443098 For to post the dbFiddle   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2620e226a7ed669d7ff94e4e36c48e98